# Windows Server Backup 2008 - Language Incompatibilities?

Tags: windows, backup, remote

I have 2 Windows 2008 Server R2 machines - one is Japanese language based and the other English.  When I try to connect from the English language server using Windows Server Backup (snap-in) I get the following message:

"An internal error has occurred in the backup engine or the computer that you are connected to remotely is running a version of backup application that is not compatible with the version on your local computer"

Both claim to be running Version 1 of Windows Server Backup.  Is remote connection to non-identical language server OSs a known problem?

Specifically this is seen when attempting the "Connect To Another Server" in the action pane of Windows Server Backup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Microsoft Multilingual packs into the English system(s)? 
A quick Google search yields: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=03831393-eef7-48a5-a69f-0ce72b883df2&displaylang=en